# Pure ftpd not found in netstat

Tags: pureftpd

I have a problem with pureftpd. It stoped suddnly. 
i run this command `netstat -tap | grep ftp` but didn't get any output. I run this command `nmap my ip` and got just http, https and ssh ports listed. 
It seems pur ftpd not working.

In var/log/pure-ftpd/transfer.log is empty.

I have open all required ports in iptables:

```
-A INPUT --protocol tcp --match tcp --destination-port 21 --match state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT --protocol tcp --match tcp --source-port 1024:65535 --destination-port 1024:65535 --match conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED --match comment --comment "Allow passive inbound connections" -j ACCEPT
```

I tried to stop/start pure-ftpd.

It seems port 21 is closed when i checkd port open. 
I dont know why pureftpd not BIND any ports.

When i tried to connect through filezilla i got this massage ECONNREFUSED - Connection refused by server

Any idea how to find what is the problem?

Comment: Is the pure-ftpd process alive? If it is, did you run netstat as root?

Comment: How can i check if its alive? yes i run netstat as root.

Comment: something along the lines of `ps -ef |grep ftp`

Comment: I got only those:
'/usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
/usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
grep ftp'

Comment: It seems not alive?

Comment: IIRC pure-ftp should log into syslog if it fails to start for some reason. Is there anything related in `/var/log/messages` (or wherever your syslog goes)?

Comment: When i restart pureftpd i got this in syslog: `systemd[1]: Started pure-ftpd.service.`

Comment: ..but the process still won't appear. Strange. Does `systemctl status pure-ftpd` have anything useful to say? Have you by any chance recently migrated your pure-ftpd config over from a non-systemd environment?

Comment: Output:
`● pure-ftpd.service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/pure-ftpd; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Tue 2017-10-31 13:12:34 CET; 6min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 2837 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/pure-ftpd stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 2849 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/pure-ftpd start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Oct 31 13:12:34 systemd[1]: Starting pure-ftpd.service...
Oct 31 13:12:34 systemd[1]: Started pure-ftpd.service.`

I didnt migrate, ftp suddenly stoped.

Comment: Finally i fix this:
I totally uninstalled purge-ftpd and reinstalled. Now everything worked.

Comment: Excellent! Sorry I couldn’t be of more help, I had urgent business elsewhere.